# Have button switch background color to background color of displayed elements

Tags: jquery, css, background

My client wants a button's background color in my page to automatically switch to the background color of the div elements on display. Is there anyway to do this with CSS or do I have to use jQuery?

My HTML

```
<h1>news</h1>
<div class="items">
    <div class="item-1" style="display: none;">
        <h2>News item 1</h2>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam. </p>  
    </div>
    <div class="item-2" style="display: none;">
        <h2>News item 2</h2>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam. </p>  
    </div>
    <div class="item-3" style="display: none;">
        <h2>News item 3</h2>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam. </p>  
    </div>
    <div class="item-4" style="display: block;">
        <h2>News item 4</h2>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam. </p>  
    </div>
    <div class="item-5" style="display: none;">
        <h2>News item 5</h2>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam. </p>  
    </div>
</div>
<button>back</button>
```

My CSS

```
body
    {    
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #333;
    }

h1, button
    {    
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

.items
    {    
        color: #fff;
    }

.item-1 h2, .item-1 p
    {    
        background: #c00;
    }

.item-2 h2, .item-2 p
    {    
        background: #0c0;
    }

.item-3 h2, .item-3 p
    {    
        background: #00c;
    }

.item-4 h2, .item-4 p
    {    
        background: #00c;
    }

.item-5 h2, .item-5 p
    {    
        background: #333;
    }

button
    {    

    }
```

[My JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c20guk0t/1/)

Comment: Css is not dynamic, you need javascript to change the style dynamically on button click.

Comment: You've to use jquery/javaScript. You just have to change the class name of the div when clicking the button.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Please let me know if my answer is working for you

Answer (score 0):

You could move your button into the wrapping `div` then apply a class to that wrapper which propagates the changes to the news items and the button:

```
<h1>news</h1>
<div class="items color-1">
    <div class="item" style="display: none;">
        <h2>News item 1</h2>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam. </p>  
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="display: none;">
        <h2>News item 2</h2>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam. </p>  
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="display: none;">
        <h2>News item 3</h2>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam. </p>  
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="display: block;">
        <h2>News item 4</h2>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam. </p>  
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="display: none;">
        <h2>News item 5</h2>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam. </p>  
    </div>
    <button>back</button>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.color-1 .item h2, .color-1 .item p, .color-1 button
{    
    background: #c00;
}

.color-2 .item h2, .color-2 .item p, .color-2 button
{    
    background: #0c0;
}

# Etc...
```

This has the added benefit of improving the use of classes.  Basically: you don't really want unique classes such as "item-1", "item-2", etc. `id`s are better suited to that as you should only ever use one `id` at a time, whereas a `class` is re-usable.

Answer (score 0):

To keep this as is, you'll have to craft up some JS. Here is a solution to style the button color of the current `<div>` which has `display: block`

```
$('button').css('background-color', $('.items > div[style="display: block;"] > h2').css('background-color'))
```

### **[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/a167ux7x/)**